# Rolling back after a failed transaction

Tags: flask, transactions, sqlalchemy

I have an operation where a parent model needs to be created with some amount of child models.  If the creation of any of these instances fails, the whole thing needs to be canceled.  The parent model and its children should **not** exist in the database if an error is raised.

The code I have:

```
transaction = db.engine.connect().begin()

try:
    parent = ParentModel()
    db.session.add(parent)
    db.session.commit()

    child = ChildModel(parent_id=parent.id)
    db.session.add(child)
    db.session.commit()

    # An error occurs.  We need to rollback the saved parent model.
    raise HTTPException() # from werkzeug
except:
    transaction.rollback()

transaction.commit()
```

My test:

```
def test(self):
    # call the above operation
    ParentModel.query.filter_by(id=1).first() # returns the parent model
```

Comment: To rollback your transaction, you can use `transaction.rollback()`.

Comment: @dirn `rollback` doesn't remove the previously saved models.  I've updated the op with my current setup.

Comment: The problem is that you call `commit` on the session. `transaction` and `session` are two different sessions. Are you trying to nest them?

Comment: @dirn If I just `add` the model (without committing it) it will still persist.  I can add a model and immediately rollback.  But querying for the model yields it.  I'm not trying to nest.  My real code is flat like the above.

Comment: You'll need to turn off autocommit. How depends on where `db.session` comes from. Is that Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy turns on autocommit by default. In order to rollback a transaction, you need to turn it off. Instead of

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)  # or whatever variation you use
```

use

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={'autocommit': False})
```

This will allow you to add several objects to `db.session` before either committing or rolling back.

With this change, you can remove your references to `transaction`.

Comment: I used this with a combination of nested `try except` blocks and `session.begin(subtransactions=True)`.  Thanks for all your help!